# CLR class memory layout

Tags: .net, clr

What is the memory layout of a CLR class?

Coming from a C++ background, the memory layout of a C++ class with virtual functions starts with a v-table pointer, and then the data members of the class follow in memory.

Do CLR classes with virtual functions have a v-table pointer? Is this pointer the first field in the class memory layout? Are there any extra fields in a CLR class memory layout in addition to programmers' defined data members? And what do these extra fields represent?

Comment: the memory layout of C# classes is usually determined by the JITTER and thus only manifested at runtime (although there are some exceptions).

Comment: C# has nothing to say about the memory layout. This is about CLR classes.

Comment: If you do want to see the VTable in a more practical way, you can follow posts like this to run `!DumpMT -MD address` command at WinDbg, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kristoffer/2007/01/02/setting-a-breakpoint-in-managed-code-using-windbg/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's implementation specific, but [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20080919091745/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx) gives a description of what was present in the Microsoft .NET implementation, for CLR v1.1. I *suspect* it's the same for CLR v2 and v4, but I couldn't guarantee it. Look for a section called "ObjectInstance" for the details - but you may find the whole article interesting.

According to the article, there are basically two bits of header: the *sync block* which is used for locking, and the *type reference* which is basically a pointer to type information (including the vtable).

A more recent - but potentially still pre-.NET-core article is [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-4-fields-layout/).

Comment: This link is broken. :(

Comment: @MrAnderson updated links are added at a separate answer.

Comment: The article covers the CLR 1.1, not the V2...

Comment: @odalet: Hmm, yes - not sure why I missed that. Will edit the answer; I'd love to provide a more recent article, but I don't know of one.

Comment: There seems to be worthy information in this blog series: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-4-fields-layout/

Comment: @odalet: Added a link.

Answer (score 1):

The original "Jit and Run" article is [still around, as a chm file](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineMay2005en-us.chm).  Just follow the [MSDN instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues) to be able to read:

> On most versions of windows you must first save these files to your
>   local machine, and then unblock the file in order to read it. To
>   unblock a file, right click on it, and select properties, and then
>   select the ‘unblock’ button. The content will then be available to
>   read

However, the venerable Jon Skeet guessed wrong - and object memory layout has indeed changed. Sasha Goldstein gives an up-to-date (CLR v4) survey of the layout, [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/03/15/virtual-method-dispatch-and-object-layout-changes-in-clr-40/).

Comment: The link to Sasha Goldshtein's blog is dead. See it on the Internet Archive, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200108021433/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/03/15/virtual-method-dispatch-and-object-layout-changes-in-clr-40/).